# Not sure how to display results in a new activity using Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, toast

Hi i have a problem and i am new to android development... i want to display the results in a new activity once the submit button is pressed instead of using the toast feature but i am not sure how i do it, any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_system);
    RadioGroup gender = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    gender.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (checkedId) {
            case R.id.answer1A:
                ans1 = 1;
                break;
            case R.id.answer1B:
                ans1 = 2;
                break;
            }
        }
    });
    RadioGroup nutrition = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
    nutrition.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (checkedId) {
            case R.id.answer2A:
                ans2 = 1;
                break;
            case R.id.answer2B:
                ans2 = 2;
                break;
            }
        }
    });


    btnSubmitQuiz = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    btnSubmitQuiz.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // 1
            if (ans1 == 1 && ans2 == 1) {

                Toast.makeText(SystemActivity .this, "Well done", 5).show();

            }

                else {
                    Toast.makeText(SystemActivity .this, "Fail", 5).show();




            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.system, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method,

```
private void displayResult(String result) {
   Intent i = new Intent(this, showResult.class);
   i.putExtra("unique_constant", result);
   startActivity(i);
}
```

In place of toast write ,

`displayResult("Well done");`

Create a new Activity named showResult, make sure it's added in AndroidManifest file. Add a textView in layout.

in oncreate method write,

`String result = getIntent().getStringExtra("unique_constant");
    TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewId);
    txtView.setText(result);`